# Acessing "a" element of an array using jquery

Tags: jquery, element

I have this code:

```
var al_normal = $("#tables a");
```

Now I want to access the element of index 0 using `$("#tables a")[0]`, but when I use this it only return the href value. How can I access the entire element attributes in this index?

Thanks!

Comment: `$("#tables a")[0]` does _not_ return the href value, it returns a reference to the first DOM element that matched the `"#tables a"` selector (or `undefined` if none matched).

Answer (score 3):

```
var al_normal = $("#tables a").get(0);
```

or

```
var al_normal = $("#tables a")[0];
```

Both return the DOM object. If you need to access it as a jQuery object, use:

```
var al_normal = $("#tables a").eq(0);
```

Further info: http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: What's the difference (other than the syntax)?

Comment: @SLaks ahh cool. I always thought they both returned the dom element

Comment: `.get(0)` returns a DOM element too, it's just a slower version of `[0]`. To return a jQuery object with the specified element use `.eq()`.

Comment: you're right, they both return the dom element. I just didn't know that $("#tables a")[0] worked.

Comment: ok, thanks, but I can't raise a click event using $("#tables a")[0].click(), why?

Comment: @lincolnmorais That returns the DOM element. Try the third example that returns a jQuery object: `$("#tables a").eq(0).click();`

Answer (score 0):

in this way:

```
$("#tables a").each(function(index){
    if (index==0){
        $(this) //your object
    }else{
        return false
    }
})
```

Comment: Nah. But I have found that if something I'm doing seems unnecessarily difficult or complex, there's probably a better way.

Comment: What i wrote aren't difficult or complex, are just made without thinking ;) **my fault**